# Review queues : redundantly duplicating… at least… the automated comment

Tags: bug

[On Feb 2, within the *late answers* review queue, I had recommended deletion of some answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/460534)
This incidentally triggering some automated comment from my user.

How comes that yesterday (Feb 7) [I get the very same answer to review as part of the *Low quality posts* review queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/460840) ?

WTF ? I already had my say about it.
OK… Nevermind !… it's not the same queue… I possibly had forgotten something, not scrupulously followed the procedure, whatever, I reiterate my reco !

This incidentally leading to… duplicating the comment the system had made in my name.

When realizing the indeed disgraceful duplicate of some comment of mine, I incidentally browsed the QA and deleted the duplicated comment.
Isn't that work overkill with regards to what is actually, since the very beginning nothing but a low quality post ?

There must be a bug somewhere. To be handled in some way or another.
Are review queues so easy to empty that whatever post should be reviewed twice (by the same user) ?
(131 first questions & 37 first answers remaining todate for the record)

Ideally, whatever post I already reviewed in some queue should not be presented to me as part of another queue (this frequently happens with regards to (late answers / first answers queues) & (close votes / first questions)).

In case this would require too hard rework then either ensure that no automated comment can be posted twice or… at the very minimum, automated comments should be credited to whatever (already-known-disgraceful ^^) *community* user.
I don't tolerate that my left hand ignores what my right hand achieves… I can accept this from the *community* user though :-).

---

Possibly OT : How comes I just cannot "*start a bounty*" in this meta? (As I would be able to on meta_SE). For the sole sake of staying  on topic, let's restrict to this topic in particular.
If find that honestly and scrupulously reviewing queues is a hard work. I'd be just happy spending my credit if it could just contribute to ease that work.

Answer (score 2):

I can’t do anything about the appearance of the same post in multiple queues, so I’ll ignore that.

As far as duplicating comments goes, you can avoid that by choosing the first option in the available comments:

[image: The “Add a comment for the author?” dialog with “No comment needed” selected]

I use this in a number of circumstances:

1. if someone else (including perhaps myself in a previous review in another queue) has already left an appropriate comment
2. if I have left a different comment, entered manually
3. perhaps controversially, if I’m voting to delete the post and I have serious doubts as to the usefulness of any comment I will leave

The latter is in part influenced by the fact that some of the canned comments don’t work all that well, and I haven’t bothered building up my own set of canned comments. (Typically, “This does not really answer the question” when it doesn’t answer the question *at all*.)

It’s perhaps also worth pointing out that whenever a post in review bothers you — you can’t decide what the appropriate course of action is, or you’ve already reviewed it and don’t want to review it again — you can always skip it:

[image: The “Submit” and “Skip” buttons]

Finally, regarding your last question about bonuses, this is probably a side-effect of the fact that voting actions on meta sites (other than [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) itself) don’t have any effect on reputation. See [Bounty-like feature on metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231215/285232).